# I've been working with velocity recently, but I made a big mess, what should I do?

Tags: servlets, request, velocity

I got this program, that I made: http://www.2shared.com/file/73q6K9Yy/testv.html
The Login.java is the servlet, that should use the login.vm template, and modify it. It doesn't do anything, and I don't understand why.
In the function:

```
public Template handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Context ctx )
```

If I put:

```
 error= (String) request.getAttribute("error");
 ctx.put("error", error);
```

It doesn't do anything.
IF I put:

```
 error= request.getAttribute("error").toString();
 ctx.put("error", error);
```

I get a Java null pointer exception.
BUT if I put:

```
 ctx.put("error","this is a string");
```

It changes the variable of the template login.vm into that string.
Why doesn't it get the Attribute from the request, what I'm a doing wrong.

PS: If I press the Register button, it should redirect me to the "/reg.jsp" page. I made this only to see if it works, and it doesn't. Made the same program in MVC, with jsp's but I need to make it with velocity, for my internship.

Comment: 10x Andrew Aylett for making my question more viewable. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that there is no attribute under the "error" key in your request. It has nothing to do with Velocity itself. If you check the line number the null exception occurs at, it should be the first line of your code excerpt.

Note that in a web context, you should use the VelocityViewServlet, from the velocity-tools subproject, rather than the deprecated VelocityServlet that will disappear in next versions.

Comment: I changed it to VelocityViewServlet, and the Properties class to ExtendedProperties ( had an error over there, after changing to extends VelocityViewServlet) and now, when i run the program i get an error like this one:

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet velo.Login threw exception

What does it mean?

Comment: I changed it to error= request.getAttribute("error").toString(); to see why do i have a java null pointer exception, and the error, is at this line, it all works fine, till it gets to it. I tried putting a request.getAttribute("error").toString() in other parts of the code, not in the Template function and no errors.
PS: In the template (login.vm) how do i declare <%@page import="a.userBean"%>

Comment: Internal errors generally have a root cause which gives more informations. You should check your servlet container log file if the displayed internal error is not explicit enough. If you don't solve related problems by yourself, please try to identify and post here only the most relevant lines. Your P.S. has nothing to do with your original question. I guess you will have to put your userBean somewhere (why not as a session attribute?) from your Java code. Remember that you can reach J2EE attributes from within your templates with $request, $session and $application.

Comment: 10x, will do so as soon as i get back to the office